# jpgraph how set y-axis scale with a increase

Tags: php, jpgraph

I want define a y-axis with a configured numbers since 30 to 100 as example 30 35 40 45 ... 95, 100.
I set a scale:

```
$graph->SetScale("intint",30,100);
```

The result is 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 but I want a increase of 5.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's done via [AxisPrototype::SetTextTickInterval($aStep, $aStart)](http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/classref/AxisPrototype.html#_AXISPROTOTYPE_SETTEXTTICKINTERVAL).